# jonySource.com metrics errors in React app with Stripe

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

All of a sudden, I started seeing these errors in the console when I run my `React.js` app that uses `Stripe` for payments.

```
Refused to load the script 'https://jonysource.com/optout/get?jsonp=__mtz_cb_644179626&key=213db237bbd6bf854a&t=1562700089161' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

script @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1
jsonp @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1
(anonymous) @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:2
(anonymous) @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:2
ready @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1
b @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:1
(anonymous) @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:2
(anonymous) @ 213db237bbd6bf854a.js:2
```

As you can see in the image, there are quite  a few of them back to back.

[image]

Any idea what this is? I have no idea where it came from and what `jonysource.com` is which doesn't even come up when you enter the URL in your browser.

Comment: Please paste the output of your error messages. do not post pictures of text.

Comment: I started seeing this, just this evening too. I've just spent the last couple of hours trying to track it down, without much luck. I believe it's also linked to fastandprettysearch.com and laubeyrietechnology.com. I'm not sure what has installed these on Chrome though, perhaps a vulnerability in a chrome extension. I'm finding it quite hard to trace the source

Comment: @Zief Now that you mentioned fastandprettysearch.com and the other URL, I thought this might be related to the browser, in my case it's Google Chrome. I decided to test my app in the new version of Edge which is based on Chromium and I did NOT get those errors. What browser are you using? Can you test your app in a different browser?

Comment: @Zief I also tested in regular Edge and again I did NOT get those errors. For some reason, Google Chrome -- or some Chrome app -- started doing this. I don't remember adding any Chrome apps recently and it's hard to believe Chrome would do this but it definitely appears to be caused by the browser.

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Windows. I'm not writing or testing any app at the moment. Best guess is that it is a vulnerability in a chrome extension, someone has found a clever way through open source npm package or something. Or a malicious website

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the Apps Launcher extension installed in Chrome? I found reference to jonysource.com in the logs for this extension. Upon disabling the extension, I no longer see jonysource.com in my list

Comment: Thanks. Is not this an extension from Google? (I just disabled it. And it is gone from the Chrome Web Store now.)

Comment: This thread has some info:
https://community.kaspersky.com/kaspersky-internet-security-13/kis19-keeps-alerting-me-about-blocked-file-cannot-trace-origin-2138. (I just opened a support request on Kaspersky.)

Comment: And here is a thread on Google Chrome Help, but no info (except the thread above).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find out what was causing this, but it definitely seemed suspect. At the very least it was changing search results from Google, as you could see this happening, it wasn't fast enough to do it before you could see the changes. Hopefully it was just limited to promoting its own sites and adverts. I also had a suspcion though that it could track other data, possibly even key presses. 
Windows defender didn't pick it up, and I have no idea how it got into Chrome. 
The only way I could remove it was removing chrome and all the browsing data, and starting fresh. Unfortunately lost a few things but hopefully rid of some clever javascript malware

Comment: I also noticed that Windows Defender did not pick it up. So I installed Kaspersky's free edition. (I have not read about virus for some years, but Kaspersky seemed to be a solid alternative.) Followed the instructions from Kaspersky. And then finally disabled the Apps Launcher Chrome extension (which is not in the Chrome Web Store at the moment). The problem is at least at face level gone. I will keep an eye on it, but there is (as usual for the komplex part of a problem) little info on the Internet yet.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the same thing on my chrome browser too.[image]